# noData value not updating when the state changes in React

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts, no-data

I have a state which holds the chart option. In that config I initialised value of noData with a value (actually wanted to initialise with an empty string to avoid showing "No data to display" for a moment before the original data gets plotted. But initialised with another value to illustrate the issue).

And in the useEffect I set the actual chart option with series data and other props values.

**Actual behaviour**
When there is no data, chart shows the initial value of noData. It should show the updated value.

Live demo with steps to reproduce
https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-tesla-pqzqdd?file=/src/App.js

Product version
Highcharts - 10.3.2

**The primary goal is to avoid showing "No data to display" during the initial render**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import HighchartsReact from "highcharts-react-official";
import Highcharts from "highcharts";
import drilldown from "highcharts/modules/drilldown.js";
import NoDataToDisplay from "highcharts/modules/no-data-to-display";

drilldown(Highcharts);
NoDataToDisplay(Highcharts);

const App = () => {
  const [chartOption, setChartOption] = useState({
    chart: {
      backgroundColor: "transparent",
      height: 350
    },
    title: { text: "" },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    accessibility: {
      enabled: false
    },
    lang: {
      noData: "Initial value of noData"
    }
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setChartData();
  }, []);

  const setChartData = () => {
    const options = {
      chart: {
        type: "line",
        backgroundColor: "transparent",
        height: 350,
        animation: false
      },
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },
      accessibility: {
        enabled: false
      },
      lang: {
        noData: "No data to display"
      },
      yAxis: {
        gridLineColor: "transparent"
      },
      series: []
    };
    setChartOption(options);
  };

  return <HighchartsReact options={chartOption} highcharts={Highcharts} />;
};

export default App;
```

When there is no data, chart should show the updated value of noData. The state value is getting updated correctly, but chart isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `lang` options are global and can not be changed during the update.

As a solution, you can update the global options through `setOptions` and enable the `immutable` option.

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
  lang: {
    noData: "No data to display"
  }
});
```

---

Alternatively, you can display the whole component only if data is received, like [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-firefly-zn34-zn345z?file=/src/App.js).

---

**Live demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-curie-wryzl-wryzlc?file=/src/App.js

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/lang

Comment: If I add `immutable={true}` and actually have data, it still shows "No data to display".
Please check the demo [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-curie-wryzl-forked-fn7ycj?file=/src/App.js) @ppotaczek

Comment: Hi @Bipin MV, That's because your `series` is an object and it should be an array of objects. Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-curie-wryzl-fqvy5z?file=/src/App.js